# Lose connection after pasting blueprint ship

Tags: space-engineers

My friend created a new online creative world for friends only. After I joined I had no problems with building stuff.
But from the moment I paste a small ship from my blueprints, I lose connection to the server. Allow copy/paste is enabled in the world.

I don't understand why this happens. I tried reconnecting several time and always the same problem. Paste my ship, connection lost.

Is there a fix?

Comment: Maybe it contains a block that was removed from the game itself or a block from a mod which is not on the server? Check if your blueprint is 100% vanilla blocks.

Comment: afraid not it was a new ship created on the same day as I tried the copy paste. Only have the game for a few days after the steam sales. Also I have not installed a single mod as of yet.

Comment: Is it with one blueprint or with all of them?

Comment: All of them that I tried so far. 2 Large ships, 3 small fighters and a small miner.

Comment: Have you tried a reinstall of the game?

Comment: I have verified the game via steam, and the game installation should be ok. (Also I can copy paste in offline worlds). I'm thinking in the direction that the server is out of sync after I paste something. But I 'm not sure and how to check/solve it. :/